# Cygwin mounted drive not accessible from remote machine

Tags: windows, mount, cygwin, putty, openssh

I have a mounted share drive `l:` on a Windows 7 64 bit machine I will call *box1*.  In Cygwin on *box1*, I type `mount` and the mounted drive shows up correctly as `L: on /cygdrive/l type ntfs (binary)`.
When I do `cd l:` it correctly changes directory to the mounted drive and I can see files (`ls`) etc...

I have another Windows 7 64 bit machine I will call *box2*. In Putty on *box2* I can successfully login to *box1* through SSH with *box1's* credentials. When I type `mount`, the mounted drive in question shows up as `L: on /cygdrive/l type unknown (binary)`.  Note the ***unknown***.

When I try to `cd l:`, I get:

> No such file or directory

So from *box2* in Putty I can see the drive is mounted on *box1*, but I can't access the drive or files.  On *box1*, in Cygwin everything looks great, mounted as type NTFS and can see the files etc.

How can I see these files from the remote machine?